# For loop not working inside midje test?

Tags: clojure, midje

Found some odd behavior in midje, not sure if it's midje related, or due to my misunderstanding of some clojure constructs, but it's puzzling:

Inside a facts statement, a for loop is not getting called:

```
(ns t1
  (:require [midje.sweet :refer :all ] )
  )

(facts
 (println "ok") ; -- this prints fine
 (for [val '(1 2 3)] (println val)) ; this does not

  (fact "junk"
        (> (.length "aaaaha") 3) => true ))
```

Thought maybe it had something to do with the for being overwritten in the ns but calling clojure.core/for behaves similarly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[clojure.core/for](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/for) "...yields a lazy sequence..."

You need to [realize](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/realized_q) the sequence to see its side effects.

```
(doall (for [val '(1 2 3)] (println val)))
```

I'd suggest using something more appropriate like [clojure.core/doseq](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/doseq):

```
(doseq [val '(1 2 3)] (println val))
```

Comment: ahh, so the context is why the same forloop works in the repl. Thanks.

Comment: Correct, in the REPL the sequence is realized when it is printed.